# I can't make translation work in Pyramid

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid

I'm working on a project with i18n and localization, but trying to use translations simply doesn't work.  I have done an example project where I followed [the official documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/i18n.html):

My project was created by "pcreate -s starter MyProject". It can be found at https://bitbucket.org/aguirrel/translation_test/src.

I have done a lot of testing, but nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your project is OK.  One thing that may be missing is that Pyramid needs to know the locale name in order to activate a translation.

There are a few ways to do that outlined [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html#setting-the-locale):

A quick way to test that your translation is working correctly is to pass the locale as a request parameter.  As an example, you could access the web page at:

```
http://localhost:6543/?_LOCALE_=es
```